How to mount a line-voltage thermostat which doesn't fit a standard junction box?
This thermostat came with my radiant floor mat. Along with proprietary wires, it takes line voltage. However, it doesn't fit a standard junction box. Also, it did not come with any special mounting hardware. So what to do?


Line-voltage device with no UL or other NTRL mark? WiFi, but no FCC label? Are you sure this is "legal" to install?

Without dimensions I couldn't be sure - but it looks like it might fit a European-style electrical junction box (not that using one would make this any more "legal" to install in the USA). You should probably return it to Amazon/ebay/wherever you got it from and rather get something that's made and certified for the USA.

Product appears to be https://www.hotowell.com/product/en/alexa-wifi-thermostat-smart-programmable.html . It is very chinesium. It's definitely not approved in the US. I doubt it's approved in Europe either, but it at least claims to be.
